# L_0 norm in R, how to perform

Tags: r, math, vector

Does anyone know how to calculate the `L_0 norm` of a vector in R. You can't do the usual `sum(x^p)^(1/p)` when `p=0` so I was unsure if there was an easy way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Max is the L infinite norm.

Comment: @Love-R right, I was hesitating (some old remains of my maths courses...)... Then isn't "p norm" only defined for p>0 ?...

Comment: What I wrote is not a norm (or precisely Banach norm,) because it is not homogeneous. But it is used quite a lot in various applications.

Comment: @Love-R yes, it's a nice answer (+1) dusted some stuff in my brain and made me learn something :-)

Comment: Since this depends entirely on how you define the `L_0` norm, shouldn't this be too broad of a question and/or not at all about programming?

Answer (score 4):

It really depends how you define the L_0 norm. There is not a clear consensus.

> [From  wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) ℓ0 "norm" by David Donoho — whose quotation marks warn that this
>   function is not a proper norm — is the number of non-zero entries of
>   the vector x. Many authors abuse terminology by omitting the quotation
>   marks. Defining 0^0 = 0,

just use `sum(x != 0)`

Comment: can you add a link to the source of your quotation?

Comment: This seems like the best choice, thanks. was wondering if there was a way to do it inside of a norm function so I didn't have to write a separate area inside of a function for the case of a the L_0 norm but it isn't much to include an additional if statement with this.

Comment: Yes, an if statement should be ok. If this is what You were looking for, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: For floating point numerical results, you should always use `abs(x)>eps` for consistent results in the presence of rounding errors. Probably it could be even better in combination with some scale for the vector, e.g., `abs(x)>eps*max_norm`.